# How to convert list hashmap into Array using Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave, mule-esb

I have list as below

```
[{customerId="123"},{customerId="456"},{customerId="786"}]
```

I want to convert above as Array like below

```
[123,456,786]
```

Can you please help on how to achieve using dataweave

Answer (score 4):

Following code will return array

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.customerId map $ as :number
```

Please refer [dataweave-selectors](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-selectors) for more details.